# I get this error while updating and installing software : perl: warning: Setting locale failed

Tags: 11.04, server

I just installed Ubuntu 11.04 in my MT server and I keep getting this error:

```
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

It comes mostly when I try to install or upgrade software!

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just got the answer from MT :

> echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /var/lib/locales/supported.d/local
>   dpkg-reconfigure locales

It works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

Run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

If that doesn't work, try adding the following line to */etc/environment* and reboot.

```
LC_ALL="en_GB.utf8"
```

Or if you are in the US,

```
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

For additional information see:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale